# ExchangeServiceBinding: how to test a connection before I make actual calls

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using ExchangeServiceBinding for Creating/Updating/Deleting Appointments. And it works great.

Is there a way to check the Credentials I have used is valid before making a call to esb.CreateItem/esb.UpdateItem/esb.DeleteItem

Basically I want validate the credentials before Calling any of those methods !!

Any help will be appreciated... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Other than making some sort of EWS call, I don't believe there's a way to validate. Of course it sort of depends on what you mean by validate. :)

Comment: Validate meaning, if the credentials I had passed (username, password, domain, server URL) is correct or not. If that is correct and is logged in, then I will do an operation, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for sure of the credentials are valid is to try and connect to the mailbox using EWS.

In the code snippet below, it tries to Bind to the Inbox folder. If the credentials are valid then the call will be successful. If the credentials are invalid then an exception will be thrown.

```
try
{
    exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password, domain);
    exchangeService.Url = new Uri(url);

    Folder.Bind(exchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

    //if no exception thrown then Bind operation was successful and credentials are valid
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    //exception thrown -  most likely related to invalid credentials
}
```